# How do I point a folder with an express app to my apache 000-default.conf file on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, express, ssl, apache2

I currently have a domain, and want to point my folder to my apache config file, to then use certbot, but I dont know how to exactly point it. So far I've done:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName mydomain.org

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bfia
#..other stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `/var/www/html/bfia` is the directory of the express app and the rest of the needed files. As of right now, the only page that appears is the default apache page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow or deny access to that directory using the "Directoiry" module (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html). You also need to configure the directoryIndex to define which file read and present to the client (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).